# JavaFX8 Path drawing Performance

Tags: performance, opengl, javafx, stroke

i am looking for a way to draw alot of paths fast in JavaFx8, the thing is I want to animate the paths.
I tried the standard path, polyline, I also tried drawing in an graphic context/canvas. But everything is just too slow.

In a test I am rotating around 200 Rectangles 1px wide and this works perfect, if I look in the pulselogger output I see that everything gets renderd within 16ms. In comparison if I draw 200 straight lines with the path node (same visual Output as 1px Rectangles) and animate this, i am getting very bad results and the paint task in the pulselogger shows 200ms.

I guess the problem is that the path is not drawn via OpenGl instead it falls back to SW renderning.

I use alot of lineTo() in the paths I want to render, so a very unelegant way would be to draw only the round stuff with the Path node and place a rectangle over the parts where I usualy use lineTo(). I guess this would speed things up alot, but this is very unflexible and hackish.

Is there anything else I can do to get the Paths rendert fast?
I already used setSmooth(false), caching is not an option as the paths get animated.

Final plattform should be Linux now developing on Mac

Thanks Robi

Answer (score 0):

Currently JavaFX does all its path rendering in software and not in hardware and there is not much you can do about this especially if caching is not an option for you. The only possibility I see for you is to have a look at the 3D stuff. Maybe you can use a triangle mesh for your purposes. That's something I always wanted to try but never had the time to do :-)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, i will look into this tomorrow and will see if I can get some good results.
thanks

Comment: Hey i looked into this a little, but I don`t see how to use it the right way.

As I have knowledge of DirectX and hlsl, my way there would be to construct a vertex buffer and then manipulate each Point in a vertex shader based on some control points. I did not find any shader support, so I would have to do all the work on the CPU which is basicly the same as what the Path class is doing anyways, or am I wrong?

Comment: Your specific requirements are certainly not ideal for this approach but you will not know until you have tried it. I just don't see any other possibility.